# не могу понять, как мне обратиться к координатам в canvas.create_text для их дальнейшего изменения в отдельной функции def change_coord()

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd, ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = Tk()
window.title("Watermarking App")
window.geometry("1920x1280")
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.option_add("*tearOff", FALSE)


def open_file():
    global image
    global canvas

    file_path = fd.askopenfilename()
    canvas = Canvas(bg="white", width=1200, height=1200)
    canvas.pack(expand=True)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f"{file_path}"))
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=image)


def font_changed(font):
    label["font"] = font


def save_file():
    canvas.postscript(file="photo.ps", colormode="color")
    img = Image.open("photo.ps")
    img.save("photo.png", "png")


def select_font():
    window.tk.call("tk", "fontchooser", "configure", "-font", label["font"], "-command", window.register(font_changed))
    window.tk.call("tk", "fontchooser", "show")


def draw_text():
    text = label["text"]
    font = label["font"]
    canvas.create_text(100, 210, text=f"{text}", font=f"{font}", fill="black")


def write_mark():
    label["text"] = editor.get("1.0", "end")


def change_coord():
    pass


main_menu = Menu()
file_menu = Menu()
edit_menu = Menu()

main_menu.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=file_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Изменить", menu=edit_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="View")

file_menu.add_command(label="Открыть", command=open_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Сохранить", command=save_file)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Выйти")

edit_menu.add_command(label="Изменить текст", command=write_mark)
edit_menu.add_command(label="Выбор шрифта", command=select_font)
edit_menu.add_command(label="Добавить текст", command=draw_text)

label = ttk.Label(text="Как будет выглядеть текст на изображении")
label.pack(anchor=N, pady=10)

editor = Text(height=3)
editor.pack(anchor=N, pady=10)


window.config(menu=main_menu)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: canvas.create_text (и любой другой create метод объекта Canvas) возвращает id объекта. Потом по этому id с ним можно работать через методы canvas.